# File format standard for Printing Photo Books/Albums

Tags: print-design, file-format

Is there a standard for Printing Photo Books and File Formats? Is it supported by all type of printers. Is it open or proprietary? Is there a Wiki page about this?

"Printer" here means commercial album printers. I am aware of regular home printing and photo printing. But question is towards wedding album and photo album printing.

What kind of file should be input for those printers and is it standardized?

Answer (score 1):

The most broadly supported file format is PDF, which will print locally or on press.

Many online photo-book services such as Snapfish also support jpeg. I've seen non-designers lay out photo pages using photo manipulation software such as Photoshop Elements or the gimp and submit them as jpegs, although that's certainly not an approach anyone here would recommend.

A simple Google search will yield plenty of information about PDF.